# PouchDB - "Database encountered an unknown error" when trying to connect to CouchDB

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to set up pouchDB syncing but i'm having trouble connecting to couchDB remotely... I have followed [these instructions from couchDB](https://launchpad.net/~couchdb/+archive/ubuntu/stable) to install on my ubunto server - which is managed with laravel forge...though this project itself is not using laravel (just a regular html file)

Everything has installed correctly, with all expected responses

If i run: `curl localhost:5984`

I get: `{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"*******************","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"version":"14.04","name":"Ubuntu"}}`

I ran: `npm install -g add-cors-to-couchdb` and `add-cors-to-couchdb`

And I am not getting any cross-origin errors

But if i try and go to http://178.xx.xxx.xxx:5984/_utils it just hangs?

When using the following code:

```
var localdb = new PouchDB('messages');
var remotedb = new PouchDB('http://178.xx.xx.xx:5984/messages');

localdb.sync(remotedb, {live: true});
```

I get:

```
Unhandled promise rejection 

Promise 
{
    [[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", 
    [[PromiseValue]]: o
}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseValue]]: o
    error: true
    message: "Database encountered an unknown error"
    name: "unknown_error"
    status: 500
```

(taken from chrome)

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? It seems to be timing out.....any ideas why it would be doing this?

Also if I use: `ssh -L5984:127.0.0.1:5984 forge@178.xx.xx.xx`

and then go to `http://localhost:5984/_utils/` it works fine

Also replacing the remote address with `http://localhost:5984/messages` also makes the syncing work

While using this I have also checked everything has installed correctly using the "Verify Installation" and it comes back with "Your installation looks fine. Time to Relax."

Strange!

So does anyone have any ideas why I can't connect to the couchDB remotely?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to modify the `local.ini` file for your CouchDB to allow access from more IPs than just localhost.

Check your `local.ini` for this section:

```
[httpd]
;port = 5984
;bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

Change this to:

```
[httpd]
;port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

**Edit**: an even easier solution is to just set up your Nginx/Apache proxy to route http://example.com/couchdb to localhost:5984. Here's the Nginx config I use:

```
location /couchdb {
  rewrite /couchdb(.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5984;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @nlawson... Ive already done this and restarted couchdb (also confirmed it in the configuration panel)

still not working though :(

Comment: You probably also need to configure outside access to the 5984 port. This will depend on how your OS is setup.

What I always do in these cases is set up an nginx/apache proxy so that e.g. http://example.com/couchdb proxies to localhost:5984.  In nginx, I use [this config](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/3bedd08dbc17c5c3bdf7).

Comment: AWESOME! thanks very much @nlawson... your config works perfectly :)

If you want to answer the question with your last comment I will accept it as the answer

Thanks again!